# reorder items algorithm

Tags: javascript, html, reorderlist

I've got an html table thus:

```
up | dn
[ ]  Item 1
[x]  Item 2
[ ]  Item 3
[ ]  Item 4
[x]  Item 5
[ ]  Item 6
[ ]  Item 7
```

If 2 & 5 are checked and I click up, the result is:

```
up | dn
[x]  Item 2
[x]  Item 5
[ ]  Item 1
[ ]  Item 3
[ ]  Item 4
[ ]  Item 6
[ ]  Item 7
```

If I click dn, the result is:

```
up | dn
[ ]  Item 1
[ ]  Item 3
[ ]  Item 4
[ ]  Item 6
[x]  Item 2
[x]  Item 5
[ ]  Item 7
```

In other words, the items are grouped in the chosen direction, and then moved one row in that direction. Anyone have a good algorithm for this? I'm sure I can write something without much difficulty, but it seems like the kind of thing that should be "out there"....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I'm leaning toward a cut-and-paste approach, since the js frameworks make moving pieces of DOM around relatively easy.

- get checked items' rows
- get index of {top}-most checked item
- remove rows & insert them into table at {index-1}
- (of course top might be bottom, and index-1 is more complex 
  depending on direction and whether or not we're at the extreme end already)

Comment: This is the exact algorithm I was about to suggest. Way to go.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a multi-keyed sorting task.  You could use something like [jQuery UI's Sortable](http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/) interface.  Your sort condition would be something like: a.selected <=> b.selected && a.index <=> b.index.

Disregard: *You want to use the [Fisher Yates Shuffle algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth_shuffle).*

Comment: perhaps I'm not reading that carefully enough, but it seems to be about reordering in a random way, which is not what I'm asking about.